# Party Mode for Google Play Music

Tags: google-play-music

I wonder if there is a way to use "Google Play Music" with something like a "Party Mode". I just want to give my friends the possibility to browse and play my music library without giving them access to my entire Google Account.

I thought of something like a Button which locks all Google Services except Google Music. If you want to unlock it again you have to provide your password.

Is something like this allready out there? - Maybe as a plugin or Chrome add-on?

Do someone know if Google is working on such a feature?

Comment: Is "Party Mode" a feature from another music player? I'm just not familiar...

Comment: No, it isn't. I just chose this name to illustrate the use-case.
Imagine You have a party with some friends and want to use Google Music as music player. You want your friends to be able to change the current song or creating playlists. But you **dont** want to give them access to your entire google account.
I was just wondering if there is already a soulution for this.

Comment: Related post on Android Enthusiasts asking for a party mode on Android: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52547/party-mode-or-guest-access-for-google-play-music

Comment: FYI: 
I found a solution and posted it at [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/64689/40646)

Comment: You can work around this issue by transferring your playlists to text and then from that text to a playlist on another platform like YouTube or Spotify - see [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106604/140514) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not possible to give you friends access to listen to google music by your account. You could share your playlist with the share options or make them public.

Instead of google play music, you could use some of the apps that access to your music account to public music by streaming.

This may be interesting to you:
http://qca.st/

Comment: You're right, I've modified the answer with more details to be more helpful to people.