# How can I see which playlists a song is included in on Google Play Music?

Tags: google-play-music

How can I see which playlists a song is included in on Google Play Music? It'd be nice if I could click the three dots when hovering the track and click something like "Included in playlists..." to see a list.

I know I can navigate to a playlist and see the songs included in it. I also know that I can try adding a song to a playlist and it will say if it's a duplicate or not. Neither of these things are what I'm interested in.

Native would be preferable, but a userscript or third party solution would also be acceptable (although I've looked into it and can't think of a way it would be possible, which is why I'm asking here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [create a text file for your playlist data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106604/140514) and also [a text file of your song list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125423/140514) both in JSON form, you can use the following script to do just this:

### [Demo](https://jsbin.com/wekumiseya/edit?html,output)

It takes a few seconds to run when there are lots of tracks and playlists.

HTML:

```
<p>Please note that this will take a few seconds to run if you have a large amount of songs and playlists.</p>
<label>Song text file (generated from <a href="https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/108103/140514">this answer</a>): <input type="file" id="songInput"></label>
<br>
<label>Playlist text file (generated from <a href="https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106604/140514">this answer</a>): <input type="file" id="playlistInput"></label>
<br>
<textarea style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
var songInput = document.getElementById("songInput"),
    playlistInput = document.getElementById("playlistInput"),
    result = document.querySelector("textarea");

var songList, 
    playlistData;

function loadData(id, elem) {
    if(elem.files
    && elem.files[0]) {
        let myFile = elem.files[0];
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
            if(id === "songInput")
                songList = JSON.parse(e.target.result);

            if(id === "playlistInput")
                playlistData = e.target.result;

            checkBothAdded();
        });

        reader.readAsBinaryString(myFile);
    }
}

function checkBothAdded() {
    if(songList
    && playlistData) {
        getSongPlaylistData();
    }
}

/* Needed to escape song names that have (), [], etc. */
function regexEscape(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

var songData = {};
function getSongPlaylistData() {
    for(let song of songList) {
        let playlistsItsIn = [];

        /* Use regex to search the playlist file for all instances,
           add the playlist name that it's in (if any) to an array. */
        let reg = new RegExp('"([^"]*?)":(?=[^\\]]+' + regexEscape(song) + ')', "g");
        let result;
        while((result = reg.exec(playlistData)) !== null) {
            playlistsItsIn.push(result[1]);
        }

        // Update our song data object
        songData[song] = playlistsItsIn;
    }

    result.value = JSON.stringify(songData, null, '\t');
}

songInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
    loadData("songInput", this);
});

playlistInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
    loadData("playlistInput", this);
});
```